# Why would Eevee take 5 minutes to render a frame in an animation after a Blender Crash that caused a System Crash?

Tags: rendering

"Okay, so I was rendering a short animation the other day with Eevee. While it was rendering the animation, which was only 100 frames, I opened Chrome to check something on Youtube. Suddenly, things got really laggy and my system crashed. But it crashed to restore screen, stating something about an overclock failure. As far as I know, I have nothing overclocked. There were several options, and I chose "Last known good configuration." Everything restored fine. I can render a scene and it renders fine. But I if I create a short animation in Eevee, 100 frames or less, it takes FOREVER. About five minutes per frame. This in stark contrast to what it was doing before the crash. I'm using an Nvidia 2070 founder's Edition card, an i9 9900 processor, and 32gb of ram. Games run fine. It's just rendering animations now that are having a problem. I will also mention that I have an EVGA 1060 in the PC too. I'm considering removing it. When I render now, I've noticed that my GPU and CPU fans are not spinning up, which they were doing prior to the crash. I've updated my Nvidia drivers and I've reinstalled BLender. No change. Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Thank you."

Comment: Hi, first please [edit your original question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209658/an-evee-render-crashed-my-system-to-the-bios-i-restored-from-the-last-know-work). Multiple postings of the same thing is not how this site works... Second, please read the [tour] and learn how this site works. Questions that are [off topic](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic) will be closed, until they are edited to be on topic and then reopened by the community. Thanks

Comment: The "overclock error" could be due to your memory overclock profile (XMP for Intel, DOCP for AMD). Technically all memory over base speed (>2133 for DDR4) is overclocked. Maybe your frequency settings are mismatched. Besides that, almost all blender crashes are memory management related in _some_ way, so it's a good place to look.

Comment: Thank you. I just disabled XMP in my BIOS (I have an Intel I9 9900). I also set the DDR4 to default of 2900 as it was 3200. Eevee is still taking 5 minutes to render a single frame for an 80 frame low-poly animation. Cycles, using both the GPU and CPU is rendering each frame at about 10 seconds each. So, something is broken with Eevee. Has anyone else run into this? Eevee was working fine prior to the system crash it caused two nights ago when I was rendering another low poly animation.